# Is there a better way of displaying data in a table in Blazor?

Tags: html, html-table, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Blazor app, which has a table with about 20 columns.
Once data is loaded you have to scroll sideways, which is less than optimal.

Is there a better way of displaying the data?

In a UWP app I had the layout like the image below:

[image: Example of table layout]

Is there a way to display data like this image in a HTML table?

The table layout I have for the Blazor app is:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Shipment type</b></td>
            <td><b>Carrier</b></td>
            <td><b>Country of departure</b></td>
            <td><b>Shipping Company</b></td>
            <td><b>Goods description</b></td>
            <td><b>Weight or Volume</b></td>
            <td><b>Package status</b></td>
            <td><b>Actions</b></td>
            <td><b>Package file number</b></td>
            <td><b>AWB Number</b></td>
            <td><b>Manifest number</b></td>
            <td><b>Package number</b></td>
            <td><b>Package type</b></td>
            <td><b>Value</b></td>
            <td><b>Date in</b></td>
            <td><b>Date stripped</b></td>
            <td><b>ETS number</b></td>
            <td><b>Shipping method</b></td>
            <td><b>Receiver</b></td>
            <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td><b>Customer</b></td>
            <td><b>Date out</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>
            </td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One option, don't use a table. Use a `ol` or `ul` of nicely formatted items to produce something similar to your UWP app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd contemplate ditching the `table` all together. You should only use the the `table` tag when you have tabular data, but just because you have tabular data doesn't mean you *have* to use it. If you want to display as a list of items for layout reasons go for it.

Moving away from a table can give you more flexibility and easier control with media queries than a table.

In the example below, I've use and ordered list of items. Each item then contains a CSS grid to layout the data. The example is a bit rough and ready but should give you something to work with if you want to move away from the rigidity of tables

```css
.shippingItems {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.shippingItem:nth-child(odd) { 
  background-color:#EEE;
}

.shippingItem:nth-child(even) { 
  background-color:#DDD;
}  

.shippingItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.shippingItem .double{
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item__group h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="shippingItems">
  <li class="shippingItem">
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipment Type</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Carrier</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Country of departure</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipping Company</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Goods description</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Weight or Volume</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package status</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group actions">
      <h2>Actions</h2>
      <div class="item__data"><a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package file number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>AWB Number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Manifest number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package type</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Value</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group double">
      <h2>Date in</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Date stripped</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>ETS number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipping method</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Receiver</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Quantity</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Customer</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group double">
      <h2>Date out</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="shippingItem">
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipment Type</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Carrier</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Country of departure</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipping Company</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Goods description</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Weight or Volume</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package status</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group actions">
      <h2>Actions</h2>
      <div class="item__data"><a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package file number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>AWB Number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Manifest number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Package type</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Value</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group double">
      <h2>Date in</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Date stripped</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>ETS number</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Shipping method</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Receiver</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Quantity</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group">
      <h2>Customer</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__group double">
      <h2>Date out</h2>
      <div class="item__data">xxxx</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.